# Time-dependent flat line bundle

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $B$ be a finite-dimensional manifold. Suppose there is a smooth time-dependent family of flat line bundles over $B$, $\pi_t:\ell_t\rightarrow B$. Here, $\ell_t$, is the total space of the time-$t$ flat line bundle over $B$, $\pi_t$ is that bundle's projection map, and $t$ ranges over $\mathbb{R}$.

This time-dependent family of flat line bundles induces a line bundle over $B\times\mathbb{R}$, $\Pi:L\rightarrow B\times\mathbb{R}$, where $\Pi^{-1}(b,t)=\pi_t^{-1}(b)$.

Is $\Pi$ a flat line bundle over $B\times\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: I'm guessing you want the connection on $L$ to be that induced from each $\ell_t$?

Comment: @EricO.Korman I think so, but I must admit that I don't know how to construct a connection on $L$ out of a family of connections on the $\ell_t$. If you could explain how that works, then I could check the rest myself. Cheers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not going to be true in general.  Take each $\ell_t$ to be, topologically, the trivial line bundle on $B$ so $L$ is the trivial line bundle on $B\times \mathbb R$.  Now on $\ell_t$ define the connection $\nabla_t = d_B + t \alpha$ where $\alpha$ is some closed 1-form on $B$.  So each $\nabla_t$ is flat.  But the connection on $L$ is $d_{B\times\mathbb R} + t\alpha$ which has curvature $dt\wedge \alpha \ne 0$.

---

EDIT There is maybe more subtlety than I thought in defining the connection on $L$.  It seems there isn't a unique connection on $L$ that gives the given connection when you restrict to any $\ell_t$ since in the example I gave you could instead take the connection $d_{B\times \mathbb R} + t\alpha + fdt$ where $f$ is any function on $B\times \mathbb R$.  This would give $d_B + t\alpha$ when pulled back to $\ell_t$.  In the simple case when all the line bundles $\ell_t$ choose a local trivialization so that the connection is deterined by 1-forms $\omega_t$.  Then the trivialization pulls back to $L$ and you can define a connection on $L$ by using the connection forms $\omega_t$.  Then the curvature will be $dt\wedge\frac{d}{dt}\omega_t$.

It seems in some cases you could come up with a different connection though on $L$ that restricts to $\ell_t$ but has curvature 0.  In the initial example I gave if $\alpha$ happens to be exact then writing $\alpha = df$ we could form the connection on $L$ given by $d_{B\times\mathbb R} + t\alpha + f dt$.  This will be flat.

I'm not sure if there's a natural characterization of how to get a connection on $L$ from the connections on $\ell_t$.

Comment: Thanks for this. I believe that this answers my question. However, I am still a little unclear about the intuition behind building a connection on $L$ out of connections of the $\ell_t$. It seems natural to require $\nabla_Xf(b,t)=(\nabla_t)_{X_t(b)}f_t(b)$ if $X$  has no component along $\mathbb{R}$. But what is the natural way to assign a value to $\nabla_{\partial/\partial t}f$?

Comment: @JoshBurby see my edit.  hope this helps.

Comment: I just want to check that I have this straight in my head. Suppose we have a local non-vanishing section of $L$ on $U_\alpha\times I_\alpha\subset B\times\mathbb{R}$. This determines a trivialization of $L$ over $U_\alpha\times I_\alpha$. If $u$ is a section of $L$ and $X$ is a vector field on $B\times\mathbb{R}$, is the connection you mention at the end of the first paragraph in your edit given in this particular trivialization by $(\nabla_Xu)_\alpha=d_B u_\alpha+d_{\mathbb{R}}u_\alpha+u_\alpha\omega_t$?

Comment: @JoshBurby yep that's correct